# Procedure for doing western blot

Tags: lab-techniques, cell, western-blot

I am writing a step by step guide for doing a western blot for a class.  It is intended for any  one with basic Biology lab skills.  I am hoping people will review my draft and give feedback on how to improve it.  Be as critical as you like about any aspect of it, I need it to be clear and concise as well as accurate.  Any tips appreciated.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Lpprwn4s127cb0D5TQezpurbjdF9hqJZQC0H7PIovE0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to Biology S.E.! If you need any assistance, please visit [The Help Center](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: You don't mention using a rocking platform in your blocking step. It's important or else all this particulate will sediment. Also this isn't really a question